# expected str instance, list found with mail dictionnary

Tags: python

I create a function which returns a mail @ or a list of mails @ as arguments for a function which sends emails.

```
def GetRespDom(product):
    dict_resp_produit = {'APO' : 'xxxx@domain.fr',
                         'BO'     : 'xxxx@domain.fr',
                         'SIN' : ['xxx@fomain.fr','xxxx@dom.fr']}
    try:
        mail_responsable =  dict_resp_produit.get(product)
        return mail_responsable
    except IndexError as e:
        return None
```

## First case : email are correctly send with a value to toaddrs = ['xxxxxx@xxxxxxxx.fr','xxxxxx@xxxxxxx.fr']

```
def SendMail(sujet, message):
    toaddrs = ['xxxxxx@xxxxxxxx.fr','xxxxxx@xxxxxxx.fr']
    ccaddrs = ['']
    server = smtplib.SMTP()
    server.connect(SMTP)
    server.helo()
    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    msg['Subject'] = sujet
    msg['From'] = fromaddr
    msg['To'] = ','.join(toaddrs)
    msg['Cc'] = ','.join(ccaddrs)
    part = MIMEText(message, 'html')
    msg.attach(part)
    server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg.as_string())
    server.quit()
```

Second case : email are not correctly send with mail @ in function argument 
=> i got ERROR TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found

```
def SendMail(sujet, message,*dest):
    toaddrs = list(dest)
    values = [i for i in toaddrs[0]]

    server = smtplib.SMTP()
    server.connect(SMTP)
    server.helo()
    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    msg['Subject'] = sujet
    msg['From'] = fromaddr
    msg['To'] = ','.join(toaddrs)
    msg['Cc'] = ','.join(ccaddrs)
    part = MIMEText(message, 'html')
    msg.attach(part)
    server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg.as_string())
    server.quit()
```

In both case , type are similar  and with the same value: ['xxxxxx@xxxxxxx.fr', 'xxxxxx@xxxxxxx.fr']

Can you tell me how to fix it please?
Thanks a lot.
Best regards.
Theo

Answer (score 1):

`*dest`in your function definition is for capturing any additional arguments as a list. See [Function definitions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions) documentation. In the first line of your function you are creating a list of lists and then trying to merge it. Here is some code I ran to better explain it:

```
>>> def SendMailToListOfAddresses(*toaddrs):
    print ','.join(toaddrs)


>>> def SendMailToAddressList(toaddrs):
    print ','.join(toaddrs)


>>> SendMailToListOfAddresses("xxx@xxxx.com", "xxx@xxxx.com")
xxx@xxxx.com,xxx@xxxx.com
>>> SendMailToAddressList(["xxx@xxxx.com", "xxx@xxxx.com"])
xxx@xxxx.com,xxx@xxxx.com
>>> SendMailToListOfAddresses(["xxx@xxxx.com", "xxx@xxxx.com"])

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#18>", line 1, in <module>
    SendMailToListOfAddresses(["xxx@xxxx.com", "xxx@xxxx.com"])
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 2, in SendMailToListOfAddresses
    print ','.join(toaddrs)
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, list found
>>> SendMailToAddressList("xxx@xxxx.com", "xxx@xxxx.com")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#19>", line 1, in <module>
    SendMailToAddressList("xxx@xxxx.com", "xxx@xxxx.com")
TypeError: SendMailToAddressList() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
>>>
```

You can change it so something like:

```
def SendMail(subject, fromaddr, message, toaddrs, ccaddrs):
    .....
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg['From'] = fromaddr
    msg['To'] = ','.join(toaddrs)
    msg['Cc'] = ','.join(ccaddrs)
    .....
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Taken. Your answer very helped me!